# CSS Sprite navagation menu won't appear in any browser?

Tags: html, css

I am quite new to the world of HTML and CSS coding and am currently testing things out that I learn on my own website.

I have created a pretty simple nav menu I guess using CSS sprite coding, I am using Visual Studios 2012 and everything appears properly in that program, however when I try to test my webpage in any browser (IE, Google, Firefox) my nav menu just disappears. I notice that the cursor does change when I hover over the space where the nav menu should be, however as I said, no menu actually displays.

To add to that, other elements that I have in my page do appear and seem to function properly?

Here is the HTML code I am using

```
  <div class ="navmenu">
    <ul class ="navbar">
     <li class ="Aboutus"><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li class="Projects"><a href="#"></a></li>
     <li class="Contactus"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

and then the CSS

```
.navmenu
{
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar
{
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 79px;
}

.navbar li
{
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.narbar li, .navbar a
{
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
}


.Aboutus
{
  left: 0px;
  width: 174px;
  background: url('c:\users\teila\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Concept2\Concept2\Img\navMenu2.PNG') 0px 0px;
}

.Projects
{
  left: 174px;
  width: 174px;
  background: url('c:\users\teila\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Concept2\Concept2\Img\navMenu2.PNG') -174px 0px;
}

.Contactus
{
  left: 348px;
  width: 174px;
  background: url('C:\Users\Teila\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Concept2\Concept2\Img\navMenu2.PNG') -348px 0px;
}

.Aboutus a:hover
{
 background: url('C:\Users\Teila\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Concept2\Concept2\Img\navMenu2.PNG') 0px -60px;
}

.Projects a:hover
{
  background: url('C:\Users\Teila\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Concept2\Concept2\Img\navMenu2.PNG') -174px -60px;
}

.Contactus a:hover
{
  background: url('C:\Users\Teila\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Concept2\Concept2\Img\navMenu2.PNG') -348px -60px;
}
```

I've tried looking for days as to what the problem could be, hopefully somebody could help me out. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `url`s are wrong. Try using relative paths, e.g. `Img/navMenu2.PNG`.

Comment: Try hosting the images on a free image platform like imgur.com and using the direct link urls from there. Some browsers won't follow hard drive links even when they're in the correct format: `file:///C:/Users/Teila/...`

Comment: Ohh my gosh, I was afraid it was going to be something simple like that. Thanks a million for pointing that out, its working perfectly now! =)

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you have an absolute path to the image with c:/ etc. If you use the relative path sp perhaps img/ or /img/ or ../img/  using ../ to step back however folders back you need to go to reach your image folder from the css file.